# Constant related to $f(n) = f(n-1) + \frac{1}{n f(n-1)}$

Tags: asymptotics, dynamical-systems, conjectures, constants

Consider the sequence $f$ :

$$f(1) = 1$$

$$ f(n) = f(n-1) + \frac{1}{n f(n-1)}$$

Now we have for large $n$ :

$$ f(n) = \sqrt {2 \ln(n)} + \frac{1}{19} + C + eps(n) $$

Where $C$ is a constant and $eps(n)$ Goes to $0$ for large $n$.

Main question : Is $C = 0 $ ?
If not What is Its value and do we have a closed form ??

Second question : How does $eps$ behave ? Do we have a closed form ?

Comment: Your sequence is also $$f(n) = f(n-1) + \frac{n-1}{n} f(n-2),$$ which I think is easier to study, you can easily derive another initial condition.

Comment: Why is that So ?

Comment: Notice that

$$ f(n)^2 = f(1)^2 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \left( \frac{2}{k} + \frac{1}{k^2 x_{k-1}^2} \right) = 2\log n + \mathcal{O}(1). $$

Taking square root, this yields

$$f(n) = \sqrt{2 \log n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right) $$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment before giving my answer.  Deleted.

Comment: @Michael, You need not delete your answer! It is always nice to have an answer than a comment. It is my bad habit to leave things as comments, but my irrational obsession for fastidiousness doesn't let me fix it. But of course your answer is simply fine :)

Comment: @mick You have a habit of making false claims with no justifications in your questions---this is very off-putting. Why not just *ask* if your asymptotic is correct and if it could be improved? Even just writing "I think we have for large $n$:" instead of "Now we have for large $n$:" would be an improvement.

Comment: Disregard my comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get (using $\ln(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$)
$$
f(n)^2> f(n-1)^2+\frac2n\ge f(n-1)^2+2\ln(1+\frac1n)
$$
so that
$$
f(n)^2-2\ln(n+1)>f(n-1)^2-2\ln(n)>...>f(1)^2-2\ln(2)=1-2\ln(2)
$$
Now use that growth to find a bound on the error in the first inequality and work toward the claim.

After thus establishing $f(n)\approx \sqrt{2\ln(n)}$ this can be re-inserted into the original equation
\begin{align}
f(n)^2&=f(n-1)^2+\frac2n+\frac1{n^2f(n-1)^2}
=1+2\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^2f(k-1)^2}
\\&\approx 2\ln(n)+c+O\left(\frac1{n}\right)
\end{align}
so that in the square root, using $\sqrt{1+x}=1+x/2+O(x^2)$
$$
f(n)=\sqrt{2\ln(n)}+\frac{c}{2\sqrt{2\ln(n)}}+O\left(\frac1{\ln(n)^{3/2}}\right)
$$

Comment: What is $c$ ? A value ? Given by ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is a constant somewhere around the range of $[-1,2.5]$. What this really tells is that $$f(n)=\sqrt{2\ln(n)}+O\left(\sqrt{2\ln(n)}^{-1}\right)$$ so that $\frac1{19}+C$ in the original statement has to be zero.

Comment: Yes I understood that. But does C have a formula ? Like an infinite Sum ? I guess this is not important for the answer.

Comment: I mean small c ..

Comment: No, not that I can see. There is a part in there that is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\ln(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\to\gamma$, then a contribution of $\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{n^2\ln(n)}$ which has a value around $\frac1{\ln(2)}-\frac1{n\ln(n+1)}$ and further increasingly small contributions.